# Getting started on a Bayesian network word problem, solving conditional probabilities?

Tags: probability, bayesian-network

I am having a tough time getting started on a homework problem involving computing the conditional probability of some given event. The problem statement is so

> Shown below is a Bayes network representing the risk of flooding
>   sewers ($FS$) in a city as dependent on rainfall ($R$), falling leaves
>   ($FL$), thunderstorm ($TS$), and autumn ($A$). Use the conditional
>   probabilities below to determine the conditional probabilities of a
>   thunderstorm for the observable scenarios $FS \wedge A$, $FS \wedge \neg A$, $\neg FS \wedge A$,
>   and $\neg FS \wedge \neg A$.

[image]

The conditional probabilities given

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{FL:}  & P(FL|TS\wedge A) & 0.8 \\ 
\hline
\text{}  & P(FL|\neg TS\wedge A) & 0.2 \\ 
\hline
\text{}  & P(FL|TS\wedge\neg A) & 0.05 \\ 
\hline
\text{}  & P(FL|\neg TS\wedge\neg A) & 0.01 \\ 
\hline
\text{R:}  & P(R|TS) & 0.7 \\ 
\hline
\text{}  & P(R|\neg TS) & 0.1 \\ 
\hline
\text{FS:}  & P(FS|FL \wedge R) & 0.5 \\ 
\hline
\text{}  & P(FS|\neg FL \wedge R) & 0.2 \\ 
\hline
\text{}  & P(FS|FL \wedge\neg R) & 0.05 \\ 
\hline
\text{}  & P(FS|\neg FL \wedge\neg R) & 0.01 \\ 
\hline
\text{TS:}  & P(TS) & 0.5 \\ 
\hline
\text{A:}  & P(A) & 0.33 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}

---

So my first question is, and I think is probably a dumb question considering the phrase "determine the conditional probabilities", **is the question asking for $P(TS|FS, A)$ or just $P(FS, A)$**?

So assuming that is correct I think for the first one $P(TS|FS, A)$ **I think I should be using the Forward Inference rule** outlined in my lecture slides? Though I'm pretty sure I am not applying it correctly.

$$\begin{align}\
P(TS|FS, A) &= \sum\limits_{R, FL} P(FS|R,FL) P(R, FL)
\\[1ex] &+ \sum\limits_{TS} P(R|TS)P(TS)
\\[1ex] &+ \sum\limits_{TS, A} P(FL|TS, A)P(TS,A)
\end{align}$$

So my thought when applying the rule is that the first line "takes care" of $FS$ ($A$ is independent above so it is "ok") in the query; by takes care I mean accounts for its dependencies. When this first line was added then $R$ and $FL$ were introduced so the second line then, again, "takes care" of $R$ and the third does so for $FL$. None of the three lines then have any variable which does not have its dependencies in check.

I think I can then apply the chain rule to each of the lines as Forward Inference defines and finally Distribution of Sum. But from there (and well here) I am not sure if that is correct or the way to go.

**Can someone steer me in the right direction?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulas suggested by *stud_iisc* have an error: The last equality is incorrect.

If it were correct, then we could have just substituted $P(TS)$ for $P(TS|FS,A)$ -- as that last equality implies for the first factor -- right to begin with and been done.

That type of substitution can only be done by invoking the conditional independence defined by the Markov Property of Bayesian networks: I.e., only if the conditioned variables (those to the right of the "|") include (1) **all of the parents** of the node to the left of the "|" **AND** (2) **only non-descendants** of the node.  In the case of $P(TS|FS,A)$, $TS$ has no parents, and $A$ is a non-descendant of $TS$, but $FS$ **is** a descendant of $TS$.

Here's a derivation of the exact solution:

1. Move everything in the target distribution on the *right* of the conditional ("|") 
   that is *not* a root node to the left of the conditional and into the denominator using **Bayes Rule**:
       $$
       P( TS | FS, A ) = \frac{P( TS, FS | A)}{\sum_{ \forall TS}P( TS, FS | A)}
       $$
2. Move all root nodes on the *left* of the conditional to the right of the conditional
   using the **Product Rule**:
       $$
       P( TS, FS | A ) = P( FS | TS, A ) P( TS )
       $$

   - So now we have:

     $$
         P( TS | FS, A ) = \frac{P( FS | TS, A ) P( TS )}{\sum_{ \forall TS}P( FS | TS, A ) P( TS )}
         $$
3. For every single-conditional that is conditioned upon by variables other than its parents (in this case,
   $P( FS | TS, A )$), introduce the parents by applying the **Sum Rule** (i.e., marginalization);
       $$
       P( FS | TS, A ) = \sum_{ \forall FL}\sum_{ \forall R}P( FS, R, FL | TS, A )
       $$
4. Use the **Product Rule** to factor all non-marginals, non-joints, and non-single-conditionals into single-conditionals and marginals.
       $$
       P( FS | TS, A ) = \sum_{ \forall FL}\sum_{ \forall R}P( FS | TS, A, R, FL )P( R | TS, A, FL )P( FL | TS, A  )
       $$
5. Invoke the **Markov Property** of a BBN to replace all single-conditionals in which the conditioning
   variables include (1) **all** of the node's **parents** and (2) **none** of the node's **descendants**. This results in having only factors that are 
    given as node conditional probabilities in the factorization of the joint for the original network:
       $$
       P( FS | TS, A ) = \sum_{ \forall FL}\sum_{ \forall R}P( FS | R, FL )P( R | TS )P( FL | TS, A  )
       $$
6. Factor out all terms that do not reference the summed variables. This is what we must compute for all combinations of $FS$ and $A$ asked for in the problem. Each time we do so, we substitute it back into the expression for the target distribution in Step #2 above or into Step #7 below:
       $$
       P( FS | TS, A ) = \sum_{ \forall FL}P( FL | TS, A  )\sum_{ \forall R}P( FS | R, FL )P( R | TS )
       $$
7. Finally, for the sake of conciseness, we can express the target distribution
   in terms of ratios (odds):
       $$
       \begin{eqnarray*}
       P( TS=true | FS, A ) &=& \frac{1}{ 1 + \text{Odds}( TS = false | FS, A )} \\
       &=& \frac{1}{ 1 + \frac{ P(TS = false)}{P(TS = true )}\frac{P( FS | TS=false, A )}{P( FS | TS=true, A )} } \\
       \end{eqnarray*}
       $$

Hope that looks like help!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Yes, you need to compute $P(TS|FS, A)$ (and several others for your assignment.)

Applying law of total probability and chain rule properly,

$$ \begin{align} P(TS|FS, A) &= \sum_{R,FL} P(TS,R,FL|FS, A) \\ &= \sum_{R,FL} P(TS|FS, A) P(R|TS,FS, A) P(FL|R,TS,FS, A) \\  &= \sum_{R,FL} P(TS) P(R|TS) P(FL|TS, A). \end{align}$$

Comment: Following through the lecture and your hint I think I understand a bit more.. My questions still are though. When the question states $FS \wedge \neg A$ does it mean, in the more conventional terms $P(TS | FS=true, A=false)$?, if so, should I then end with a pdf for $TS$ at the end of each of the given queries?